# crear un objeto indexado por fechas

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
let arrayPrincipal = [{
    {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "13:30"
    },
    {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "14:30"
    },
    {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "15:30"
    },
    {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "16:30"
    },
    {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "17:30"
    },
    {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "22062020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "22062020",
        time: "19:30"
    },
    {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "09:30"
    },
    {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "10:30"
    },
    {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "16:30"
    }
}]
```

Necesito recorrerlo para tener un objeto indexado por las fechas que contenga los actions (key) y los time (value) correspondientes a cada fecha. Cada fecha, sin repetirse, sería una posición que contiene todos sus actions y times. El resultado final sería algo así:

```
   20052020: {
        start: "12:30",
        pause: "13:30",
        restart: "14:30",
        pause: "15:30",
        restart: "16:30",
        end: "17:30",
    },
    22062020: {
        start: "12:30",
        end: "19:30",
    },
    24072020: {
        start: "9:30",
        pause: "10:30",
        restart: "12:30",
        end: "16:30",
    }
```

Y este último quiero recorrerlo para pintar las horas.

El problema lo estoy teniendo en la forma de recorrerlos. Intento hacerlo como si fueran arrays y creo que me estoy equivocando:

```
let objetoNuevo = {}
for (let prop in arrayPrincipal) {
    console.log(arrayPrincipal[prop]);
    if (arrayPrincipal[prop] !== arrayPrincipal[prop - 1]) {
        objetoNuevo.push(arrayPrincipal[prop].fecha)
    }

}
```

con esto lo recorro pero no consigo hacer nada más. He intentando comparar la posición para que solo haga un push en caso de que la posición actual sea diferente a la anterior, pero me lo deja vacío.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arrayPrincipal = {
    0: {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    1: {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "13:30"
    },
    2: {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "14:30"
    },
    3: {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "15:30"
    },
    4: {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "16:30"
    },
    5: {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "17:30"
    },
    6: {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "22062020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    7: {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "22062020",
        time: "19:30"
    },
    8: {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "09:30"
    },
    9: {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "10:30"
    },
    10: {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    11: {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "16:30"
    }
}

const dates = [];
const dateObj = {}

for(let prop in arrayPrincipal){
  let date = arrayPrincipal[prop].fecha;
  let action = arrayPrincipal[prop].action.toLowerCase();
  let time = arrayPrincipal[prop].time;
  
  if(dates.indexOf(date) === -1){
    dates.push(date);
    dateObj[date] = {};
  }
  
  dateObj[date][action] = time;
}

console.log(dateObj);
```

Algo como eso?, amigo me queda una pequeña duda aún... ¿Por qué no simplemente creaste un array de objetos en vez de un objeto con indices de un array?

Es decir, hubiera hecho mucho mas sencillas las cosas el tener algo como esto de inicios:

```js
let arrayPrincipal = 
[
    {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "13:30"
    },
    {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "14:30"
    },
    {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "15:30"
    },
    {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "16:30"
    },
    {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "20052020",
        time: "17:30"
    },
    {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "22062020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "22062020",
        time: "19:30"
    },
    {
        action: "START",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "09:30"
    },
    {
        action: "PAUSE",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "10:30"
    },
    {
        action: "RESTART",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "12:30"
    },
    {
        action: "END",
        fecha: "24072020",
        time: "16:30"
    }
]

console.log(arrayPrincipal[0]);
```

Como vemos puede parecer que es exactamente lo mismo y que no habria diferencia alguna, pero no es así, el usar un array de objetos en vez de un objeto principal que contiene a otros hace que en el primer caso nos ahorremos digitar cada uno de los indices numericos a mano.

Ademas otra ventaja de usar un `array de objetos` en vez de un objeto que contiene a otros es que con un `array` normal tienes acceso a las funciones `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, `forEach` y muchas mas que hubiesen acortado el problema, considera usar el formato de `arreglo de objetos` las futuras vecez en vez de usar un formato de solo objetos.

Dicho esto, explicare como lo logre, vamos a centrarnos en estas lineas de aquí que son las que hacen la magia:

```
const dates = [];
const dateObj = {}

for(let prop in arrayPrincipal){
  let date = arrayPrincipal[prop].fecha;
  let action = arrayPrincipal[prop].action.toLowerCase();
  let time = arrayPrincipal[prop].time;

  if(dates.indexOf(date) === -1){
    dates.push(date);
    dateObj[date] = {};
  }

  dateObj[date][action] = time;
}

console.log(dateObj);
```

Creamos un contenedor de las fechas unicas (`dates`) y nuestro objeto contenedor del resultado esperado (`dateObj`):

```
const dates = [];
const dateObj = {}
```

Recorremos las propiedades del objeto original:

```
for(let prop in arrayPrincipal){
  ...
}
```

Dentro del ciclo obtenemos la información relevante (la información que deseas):

```
let date = arrayPrincipal[prop].fecha;
let action = arrayPrincipal[prop].action.toLowerCase();
let time = arrayPrincipal[prop].time;
```

Donde usaremos `date` como indices del nuevo objeto, `action` como el indice del `nested object` y `time` como el valor de la propiedad del `nested object`.

Miramos en nuestra lista de fechas si aún no hemos añadido esa fecha recorrida en el ciclo, si aún no la hemos añadido añadimos la nueva fecha tanto al array de fechas como al objeto resultado, ademas como valor de la propiedad fecha le asignamos un nuevo objeto vació.

```
if(dates.indexOf(date) === -1){
  dates.push(date);
  dateObj[date] = {};
}
```

Por ultimo y no menos importante, establecemos al objeto hijo la propiedad que contuviese el `action` y le asignamos como valor el tiempo.

```
dateObj[date][action] = time;
```

**Nota importante:** Existe un problema que no puede ser arreglado mediante código, y es que las propiedades que se repiten **NO** pueden existir en un objeto, es decir, cada propiedad es única y como vemos, en uno de tus objetos hay propiedades que se repetirían al momento de añadirlas a un solo objeto, esto causa que la propiedad de ese objeto tome como valor la ultima coincidencia de esa propiedad.

Por lo que cierta información **se perdera sin poder hacer nada**, a menos de que replantees una forma distinta en la que no repitas propiedades del objeto.

Comment: Recuerda que hay propiedades de los objetos que al combinarlas en uno NO pueden mantenerse, puesto que en un objeto no pueden haber propiedades repetidas, como resultado de esto se guardara el ultimo valor coincidente y los demas simplemente serán descartados para esa propiedad que se repite, no hay nada que hacer al respecto con código sin alterar la estructura que deseas.

Comment: tienes razón amigo. Me he confundido al copiar y pegar. El array que tengo al principio es como me dices. lo he editado.

Comment: Tambien he editado mi respuesta hace poco, espero sea de ayuda... mirala y me dices que tal...